# Jenkins Pipeline Groovy script: batch script issue '%20' is replaced with '0'

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline script using a git URL with whitespaces `https://username:password@project-teamprojects.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/Core - Stream`:

```
node ("master") {
  bat([script: "git push https://username:password@project-teamprojects.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/Core%20-%20Stream", encoding: "UTF-8" ])  
}
```

When this jenkins job is executed, it fails because `'%20'` is replaced with `'0'`. Log saying that:

```
git push https://username:password@project-teamprojects.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/Core0-0Stream 
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier Core0-0Stream does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://username:password@project-teamprojects.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/Core0-0Stream/' not found
```

How to encode git url properly using [bat task](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step) in jenkins pipeline script

Comment: Probably Windows replacing `%xxx` with a system variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `%20` character is most probably interpreted as a variable. You have a lot of solutions :

### Do not allow variable substitution

Remove interpolation from your bat script. For that, use `simple quotes` instead of `double quotes` :

```
bat([script: 'git push https://username:password@project-teamprojects.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/Core%20-%20Stream', encoding: "UTF-8" ])
```

### Use '+' char instead of '%20'

Plus sign should not be interpreted as a variable and should be valid as a space in URL :

```
bat([script: "git push https://username:password@project-teamprojects.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/Core+-+Stream", encoding: "UTF-8" ])
```

### Escape the interpreted character

I didn't test it but most probably with your bat script it's the `%` that gets interpreted and replaced. To avoid that you could try to escape it with a `%%` :

```
bat([script: "git push https://username:password@project-teamprojects.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/Core%%20-%%20Stream", encoding: "UTF-8" ])
```

Note : According to [this article](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php), `%` character must be escaped with another percent char, so : `%%`.

Comment: @Pom_12, unfortunately none of these work. 1st solution still replace with `0`. 2nd is saying repository not found. 3rd to escape `%` says unexpected char.

Comment: See my edited post, it seems that you need to put `%%` instead of `\%` to actually escape the `%` character... sorry, I rarely use Windows bat scripts so I have Unix-style reflexes :)